# Follow user on facebook, instagram and Youtube using API (graph API, Youtube API)

Tags: python, django, react-native, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

In my app there is a follow button, I want on click of the button, The User clicking the follow button can follow the intended user on connected social media like Facebook, Instagram and youtube. 
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @CBroe You are 100 percent Right, I have read their documentation, I can't find any way for this? Can you guide me is there any way?

Comment: Facebook does not have any API, or dedicated social plugin for this. The Like button can be used with FB pages as well, but I am not sure if a like would automatically equal a follow then (as it does with the UI on facebook.com.) I don’t know about the other networks, but I would guess it is probably a similar issue - providing an API for this, often leads to spam / fake follows, so my _guess_ would be, that they don’t provide that either.

Comment: I can't find any way for that on facebook and on Instagram, but there is a way for subscription on youtube, https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/

Comment: Thank you for your response @CBroe